# :after pseudo element and content on contenteditable

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div. I use CSS `:after` selector to append an asterix to the content.

```
<div contenteditable="true">Test content</div>

[contenteditable]:after {
  content: ' *';
}
```

http://jsbin.com/hojemaziba/edit?html,css,output

However, this causes problems. On Chrome and IE the cursor shows in a wrong place and on Firefox the asterix appears on the next line.

How should I append the asterix?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display: inline-block;` and some positioning will fix the carret position while typing.

```css
[contenteditable] {
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

[contenteditable]:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '*';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Test content</div>
```

Comment: @Kaiido yep, seen it and fixed it. The answer is updated please see again. Problem now is, if you type too much and it goes to next line the asterix stays at absolute position.

Comment: Yes, I was going to let you know about new line problem ;-) But I think that FF `<br>` insertion is actually a bug, but I don't know `contenteditable`  specs too much, so I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The absolute position is a bit tricky as the asterix should be at the end of the line and as you pointed out, if you type too much it will stay on the top.

Comment: @Mikko yes. Well it seems to be a FF bug. Not sure if you can rethink where to put the asterix. Problem would not occur if put on `:before`

Comment: @Mikko, This could be worked around by changing `top:2px;` by `bottom:0`, but to make it go to the left at new line, you would need js and insert the `*` directly into the content, no more `::after`

Comment: @Kaiido nice one! But still it stays then to the right and is not moving in front of the caret. I think that's what he wants.

Comment: @caramba, yes that's what I meant by *go to the left at new line*. And yes, I think he will need js to achieve it. I tried some hacks with already set inner content, but can't make something that works correctly...

Comment: Actually I've got one that works for FF but which messes up with chrome... https://jsfiddle.net/gebqf5bm/

Comment: @Kaiido your works fine in  my Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 .. Does this work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/gebqf5bm/1/

Comment: @caramba, on my chrome 56 it's still placing the asterisk one line after. But maybe with the solution in your answer + FF conditional...

Comment: @Mikko please see comments above and let me know if this is working for you https://jsfiddle.net/gebqf5bm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Using **position relative** is much better when text has multiple or single line.

```
div {
  display:inline-block;
}

[contenteditable]:after {
  content: ' *'; 
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  top:4px;
  padding-left:4px; 
}
```

http://codepen.io/bherumehta/pen/MJqEPp